# Formatting symbols in the glossaries package

Tags: glossaries

So I love the `glossaries` package, and have it tweaked and automated about as well as I'd like it.  However, I'm still having one issue:  how do I format the symbol in the glossary?  I'd like to have it display in a different color than the surrounding text.  MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\setglossarystyle{mcolindex}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{examp}{name={EXAMPLE},%
    description={Just showing what I mean},%
    symbol={Ex.}%
}
\begin{document}
This is my \gls{examp}.
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

I could clearly redefine the `mcolindex` glossary style, which itself is a slightly modified version of the `index` glossary style, but the package is so complete and customizable that I can't help but think there's an easier way to do it.  I tried to do it as explained in the manual `glossaries-user`:

```
\newglossarystyle{newglssty}{%
    \setglossarystyle{mcolindex}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentrysymbol}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{##1}}%
}%
\setglossarystyle{newglssty}
```

But for reasons that aren't clear to me, this produces the `glossary` key ("examp") where I'd expect the symbol to be.

Can anyone help point out what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\renewcommand*{\glossentrysymbol}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{##1}}%
```

is the wrong redefinition of `\glossentrysymbol` -- it's just defined now to print the key in blue colour, not to use the key, fetch its symbol and display this in blue colour.

One way to bypass this is to safe the original `\glossentrysymbol` command and wrap the `\textcolour{blue}{\glossentrysymbolorig{##1}}` around this in the `\renewcommand*`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\setglossarystyle{mcolindex}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{examp}{name={EXAMPLE},%
    description={Just showing what I mean},%
    symbol={Ex.}%
}

\let\glossentrysymbolorig\glossentrysymbol
\newglossarystyle{newglssty}{%
    \setglossarystyle{mcolindex}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentrysymbol}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\glossentrysymbolorig{##1}}}%
}%
\setglossarystyle{newglssty}
\begin{document}
This is my \gls{examp}.
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image]